# Failed to delete the state directory in IDE for Kafka Stream Application

Tags: java, windows, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am developing a simple Kafka Stream application which extracting messages from a topic and put it into another topic after transformation. I am using Intelij for my development.

When I debug/run this application, it works perfect if my IDE and the Kafka Server sitting in the **SAME machine**

> (i.e. with the BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG = localhost:9092 and
>   SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG = localhost:8081)

However, when I try to use another machine to do the development

> (i.e. with the BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG = XXX.XXX.XXX:9092 and
>   SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG = XXX.XXX.XXX:8081 where XXX.XXX.XXX is the
>   ip address of my Kafka),

the debug process run **without problem at the 1st time**. However, when I run 2nd time after resetting the offset, I received the following error:

```
ERROR stream-thread [main] Failed to delete the state directory. (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateDirectory:297) 
java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: \tmp\kafka-streams\my_application_id\0_0
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException:
```

If I changed `my_application_id` as `my_application_id2`, and run it, it works again at the 1st time but receiving error again if I run it again.

I have the following code in my last sentence in my application:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
```

Any advice how to solve this problem?

UPDATE:

I have reviewed the state directory created in my development machine (Windows Platform) and if I delete these directory manually before running 2nd time, no error found. I have tried to run my IDE as Administrator because I think this could be something about the permission on the folder. However, this doesn't help.

Full stack for reference:

> INFO Kafka version : 1.1.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:109) 
>   INFO Kafka commitId : fdcf75ea326b8e07 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:110) 
>   INFO stream-thread [main] Deleting state directory 0_0 for task 0_0 as user calling cleanup. (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateDirectory:281) 
>   Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:16552', transport: 'socket'
>   Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: C:\workspace\bennychan\kafka-streams\my_application_001\0_0
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateDirectory.clean(StateDirectory.java:231)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.cleanUp(KafkaStreams.java:931)
>       at com.macroviewhk.financialreport.simpleStream.start(simpleStream.java:60)
>       at com.macroviewhk.financialreport.simpleStream.main(simpleStream.java:45)
>   Caused by: java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: C:\workspace\bennychan\kafka-streams\my_application_001\0_0
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:266)
>       at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
>       at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils$1.postVisitDirectory(Utils.java:651)
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils$1.postVisitDirectory(Utils.java:634)
>       at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2688)
>       at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.delete(Utils.java:634)
>   ERROR stream-thread [main] Failed to delete the state directory. (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateDirectory:297) 
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateDirectory.cleanRemovedTasks(StateDirectory.java:287)
>   java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: C:\workspace\bennychan\kafka-streams\my_application_001\0_0
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateDirectory.clean(StateDirectory.java:228)
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:266)
>       ... 3 more
>       at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
>       at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils$1.postVisitDirectory(Utils.java:651)
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils$1.postVisitDirectory(Utils.java:634)
>       at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2688)
>       at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.delete(Utils.java:634)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateDirectory.cleanRemovedTasks(StateDirectory.java:287)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateDirectory.clean(StateDirectory.java:228)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.cleanUp(KafkaStreams.java:931)
>       at com.macroviewhk.financialreport.simpleStream.start(simpleStream.java:60)
>       at com.macroviewhk.financialreport.simpleStream.main(simpleStream.java:45)

UPDATE 2 : 
After another detailed check, the line below throwing IOException

```
Files.walkFileTree(file.toPath(), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
```

This line is located at kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar org.apache.kafka.common.utilsUtils.class

May be this is the problem with Windows system (sorry that I am not an experienced JAVA programmer).

Comment: What version are you using? Can you share the full stack trace?

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasJ.Sax. I have edited my question with new findings and stack trace

Comment: The Kafka devs have stated that they don't test on Windows.  May I suggest you try all this in some Vagrant Linux VMs?  There is an excellent project on GitHub, [eucuepo/vagrant-kafka](https://github.com/eucuepo/vagrant-kafka), all set up with zookeepers and brokers and all that.  I suspect the problem is that windows locks files (SHARE_DENY_XXX) by default whereas Nixes do not.

Comment: Thanks @F.P.Freely. I have given up to do development in Windows now. I am now using same machine where Kafka is setup for development task.

Comment: When it fails, can you check what files are in the directory?

Comment: There is no file but only the folders only. For example, C:\\kafka-streams\my_application_001\0_0 and there is nothing in the 0_0 folder in windows

Answer (score 7):

For googlers..

I'm currently using this Scala code for helping windows guys to handle deletion of state store.

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase.contains("windows")) {
  logger.info("WINDOWS OS MODE - Cleanup state store.")
  try {
    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File("/tmp/kafka-streams/" + config.getProperty("application.id")))
    FileUtils.forceMkdir(new File("/tmp/kafka-streams/" + config.getProperty("application.id")))
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => logger.error(e.toString)
  }
}
else {
  streams.cleanUp()
}
```

Comment: It worked. Don't forget to add `Apache Commons IO` dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ideano1 that is seems to be related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6647 -- what you can try is, to explicitly call `KafkaStreams#cleanUp()` between tests. It's unclear why there are issues at Window-OS. Atm, all testing happens on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

This is what we've implemented that works on Windows. This is written in Kotlin.

Version used : kafka-streams-test-utils:2.3.0.

The key is to catch the exception. The tests will pass as long as you catch the exception raised by `testDriver.close()`even if you don't delete the directory. However, cleaning up the directory makes your unit tests independent and repeatable.

```
val directory = "test"

@BeforeEach
fun setup(){
    //other code omitted for setting the props
    props.setProperty(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG,directory)
}

@AfterEach
fun tearDown(){
    try{
        testDriver.close()
    }catch(exception: Exception){
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(File(directory)) //there is a bug on Windows that does not delete the state directory properly. In order for the test to pass, the directory must be deleted manually
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For tests (but not only if you afford so) one could use an `IN_MEMORY("in-memory")` store for each `KTable` created (directly or indirectly, by e.g. aggregations); this avoids the creation of any directory such that the error no longer occurs.